# CipherSuite TLS_RSA and TLS_PKS

Tags: windows, security, iis, windows-server, tls1.3

for some security reason i only allow to use TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_with_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 , so
i disabled all weak Ciphersuite
but when I disable
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

my website gets " Unable to connect "  and even my startup method doesn't call

information :

Asp.Net 4.8

AspNet.Mvc version 5.2.7

Debug environment= on Windows 10 , server = Windows Server 2019

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_with_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` requires you to use a so-called "ECC certificate" (whose signature algorithm should be ECDSA). That often is not the case, and yours hit the same.

Either you switch to such a certificate in site binding, or you re-enable `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`.